# Cocoa: Actions Processing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

the [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596804792) which I study, to transition from C++ to Objective-C, places all the **Action Methods** into **Application Delegate** class.

The sample code within the book works. However, I am thinking, what if I have 100, or in extreme cases 500, controls in my application. Will all the controlls' actions be processed in the same Application Delegate class? This look to me as very messy.

Could you, therefore, help me to answer my question, please:

If I have many controls (buttons, processing bars, fields ... ) in my application, **is Application Delegate the only and correct place for processing all the action methods?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Books use the Application delegate because it is a convenient place to put example code.

As you write your own programs, you'll have your own hierarchy of controllers to receive action messages.

Comment: +1, hi and thanks for your response. If I understand correctly, I will rarerly use Application Delegate to process action methods. **In which cases then is it suitable, to place action methods in Application Delegate?** Especially, if there is a possiblity to create a hierarchy of controllers, as you mentioned.

Comment: The application delegate is just that - a class to handle the [delegate methods of NSApplication](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). Many will say that since handling actions is not part of this protocol then action messages should not be in this class.

Comment: As this answer is sufficient to me, I am marking it as the _Accepted Answer_.